# How to calculate greatest distance between same values in array

Tags: c#, console-application

I want to write a program to calculate the longest distance between each number and the same number of this array
this is my code

```
int max_dist = 0;
for (int j= 0; j < n; j++)
{
   for (int secondelement = 1; secondelement <= n;secondelement++)
   {
      int first = array[j];
      int second = array[secondelement];
      secondelement++;
      if (first == second)
      {
         max_dist = max_dist +1;
         System.Console.WriteLine(first+""+max_dist);
         first = second;
         break;                        
      }
      else
      {
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

but something is missing and I don't know what is this because my program prints wrong values .. what's the problem and where is the wrong

```
for example if my array is
```

2 3 5 7 3

```
out put is 

3  3
```

2 7 5 7 3 4 5 6 7

```
    out put is 

7 4
```

1 3 5 7 1

```
  out put is 

    1  3
```

it's mean number x longest distance is y to occurs again 
    NOTE : Number may found many times

Comment: i edited my question

Comment: i did now see the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first mistake is that you are increasing second element inside the cycle. The second mistake is that you increment max_dist instead of calculating the difference between the indexes. It is also pointless to calculate first in each iteration of the second cycle and you should start the inner cycle from the next of the current index of the first cycle. And it is also pointless to break from the cycle.

EDIT:

Let's fix your code:

```
for (int j= 0; j < n; j++)
{
   int max_dist = 0;
   int first = array[j];
   for (int secondelement = j + 1; secondelement < n;secondelement++)
   {
      int second = array[secondelement];
      if (first == second)
      {
         if (max_dist < secondelement - j)
         {
            max_dist = secondelement - j;
         }
         first = second;
      }
   }
   System.Console.WriteLine(first+" "+max_dist);
}
```

EDIT:

You will also need to avoid duplicate outputs:

```
for (int j= 0; j < n; j++)
{
   int max_dist = 0;
   int first = array[j];
   int earlierIndex = -1;
   for (int k = 0; (earlierIndex < 0) && (k < j); k++) {
      if (first == array[k]) {
         earlierIndex = k;
      }
   }
   if (earlierIndex >= 0) continue;
   for (int secondelement = j + 1; secondelement < n;secondelement++)
   {
      int second = array[secondelement];
      if (first == second)
      {
         if (max_dist < secondelement - j)
         {
            max_dist = secondelement - j;
         }
         first = second;
      }
   }
   System.Console.WriteLine(first+" "+max_dist);
}
```

Comment: @Yasmeen at which line? Also, how many items are in your array?

Comment: I made my array is 1,2,3,4,1

Comment: In int second = array of second element line

Comment: Worked when i remove or equal ty very much

Comment: @Yasmeen you are welcome, I will edit my answer to add that info.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more then 1 number to calculate

```
var myArray = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 8, 9, 0, 4, 3, 8 }; // 4, 3 and 8
var numbers = myArray.GroupBy(x=>x).Where(x => x.Count() > 1).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();  // Selects 4, 3, 8
foreach (var n in numbers)
{
    var first = Array.IndexOf(myArray, n); //get first occurence of each number
    var last = Array.LastIndexOf(myArray, n); //get last occurence of each number
    var dist = last - first; //calculate distance
    Console.WriteLine($"Number: {n}, distance: {dist}"); //print distance
}
```